# Computer restarts instead of shutting down

Tags: shutdown

When I try to shut down, the computer restarts instead. I have tried shutting down using both GUI and CLI. I have updated the system with the command `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` but without luck. I also tried to change the grub file, but no positive results.

Answer (score 1):

Try typing:

```
sudo sync && sudo poweroff
```

WARNING: This program will instantly shut off the computer so you may want to save some data if you are currently working.

If that doesn't work too and your pc restarts, there might be a hardware or BIOS configuration problem.